# How to get the co-ordinates into function that's being called by apply() in R?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, apply

I'm trying to write my own image filtering functions and one easier style is averaging the cell neighbour values. I've got a matrix with pixel values, but instead of using a huge for loop I'm trying to use apply, but can't seem to get the current co-ordinates of a cell being "worked on".

I'm struggling to get any multi-variable function to work with `apply()`, but ideally I think I'd pass the whole matrix to the function?

```
picture = matrix(data=0,nrow=px,ncol=px)

# I then have a function that draws a few squares and adds some random noise
# Now I'd like to go through the matrix, find the cells neighbour values, avg.
 
test <- function(x,cur_matrix){
    up    = cur_matrix[i,j+1]
    left  = cur_matrix[i-1,j]
    right = cur_matrix[i+1,j]
    down  = cur_matrix[i,j-1]

    avg = ( up + down + left + right ) / 4
    x = avg
    return(x)
}

picture_2 = apply(picture, 1:2, test, cur_matrix = picture)
```

How could I pass both the matrix "picture" and the current i,j co-ords into this function?

Comment: If you need to iterate over multiple values, you will probably need `mapply` rather than `apply`. I'm not sure what you expect `picture_2` to return exactly. The code provided does not seem to be in a runnable state.

Comment: It was just to be a new edited matrix with the cell averaged values, I just wanted to store it separately so I can have both accessible to see the smoothing happening.

I'll try to read up on mapply now! Sorry it was just a rough outline of what I'd like my function to look like since the noise functions and that were quite big

Comment: I would encourage to simply use a for-loop. Then learn on how to vectorize. But a for-loop written in C/CPP will be faster

Answer (score 3):

For pixel averaging, you usually may need to consider its valid neighbors + **itself**, instead of the neighbors only (as revealed in your post).

---

## Update: Vectorized

As pointed out by [@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883863/12158757), yes, the approach given in `ftic0` (see my earliest solution) is super inefficient, both time-wisely and space-wisely.  So, in what follows, we avoid spanning the distance space as did previously and vectorize the operations like below

```
ftic1 <- function(pic) {
  p <- list(
    orig = pic,
    up = rbind(NA, pic[-nrow(pic),]),
    down = rbind(pic[-1,], NA),
    left = cbind(NA, pic[, -ncol(pic)]),
    right = cbind(pic[, -1], NA)
  )
  rowMeans(array(do.call(cbind, p), c(dim(pic), 5)), TRUE, 2)
}
```

and let's see the performance improvement

```
set.seed(0)
pic <- matrix(runif(512^2), 512)
microbenchmark(
  fonyambu = localAverage(pic),
  ftic1 = ftic1(pic),
  unit = "relative",
  times = 100L,
  check = "equal"
)
```

which shows

```
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 fonyambu 1.746054 1.753484 1.796011 1.768681 1.911893 2.17329   100
    ftic1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.00000   100
```

and `bench::mark`

```
bm <- bench::mark(
  fonyambu = localAverage(pic),
  ftic1 = ftic1(pic),
  iterations = 100L,
  check = TRUE
)
```

shows

```
> bm
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 fonyambu     28.3ms 30.2ms      31.8    59.1MB    273.     12   103      377ms
2 ftic1        14.8ms 17.2ms      55.3      38MB     73.3    43    57      778ms
# ℹ 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

## Previous Solution: Low-code version but inefficient

You can try `sapply` like this

```
# dummy picture pixel matrix
set.seed(0)
pic <- matrix(runif(30), 5)

ftic0 <- function(pic) {
  # complex coordinates, say, (1,2) is denoted by 1+2i
  idx <- row(pic) + 1i * col(pic)
  # average by neighboring pixels
  pic_out <- `dim<-`(sapply(c(idx), \(p) {
    u <- idx[abs(p - idx) <= 1] # neighbors + itself
    mean(diag(pic[Re(u), Im(u)]))
  }), dim(pic))
}

pic_out <- ftic0(pic)
```

and we will see that

```
> pic
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]
[1,] 0.8966972 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452 0.26722067
[2,] 0.2655087 0.8983897 0.20597457 0.4976992 0.9347052 0.38611409
[3,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.17655675 0.7176185 0.2121425 0.01339033
[4,] 0.5728534 0.6607978 0.68702285 0.9919061 0.6516738 0.38238796
[5,] 0.9082078 0.6291140 0.38410372 0.3800352 0.1255551 0.86969085
> pic_out
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.4546293 0.5146388 0.3098210 0.5266930 0.6873031 0.4769267
[2,] 0.6081799 0.5032460 0.3680813 0.6251678 0.5616213 0.4003576
[3,] 0.5387903 0.6105087 0.5463696 0.5191846 0.5059061 0.2485087
[4,] 0.6284957 0.6988927 0.5800774 0.6856513 0.4727331 0.4792857
[5,] 0.7033917 0.6455558 0.5200689 0.4704000 0.5067387 0.4592113
```

In the approach above, you should be aware of treatment for edge and corner pixels:

- Each corner pixel has `2` neighbors for averaging
- Each edge pixel has `3` neighbors for averaging

Comment: Wow this is really interesting. So you're noting co-ordinates as complex numbers instead of classic [I,j]. Is that how to get co-ordinates inside the function being applied?

Comment: @HopelessUser69 yes, exactly

Comment: Ahh that's smart! I'm quite unfamiliar with how the neighbour cells are being generated, what's the \p and its relevance? Especially in that u term after?

Comment: @HopelessUser69 `p` is the coordinate of current pixel, and `abs(p-idx)<=1` means to find the neighbors ( since they should have distance `1`  when computing the modulo of two complex points)

Comment: This is quite inneficient as the picture grows. ie each time you are subtracting the whole idx. If p=100, why do we care care to subtract 1:50 for example? And even after subtraction, you do get the abs of all the indices, do the relative operator to all the indices, then only pick the 5 results that remain. Very inneficient

Comment: @Onyambu yes, thanks for pointing out the efficiency issue. Yes, I was focusing too much on the shortening the code lines but forgot about the performance. Please check my update.

Comment: Just noticed how easy this is!

Comment: @Onyambu I made another version, using `for` loops. You can take a look at the speed and memory use, it would be of your interest.

Answer (score 2):

The method presented above is quite inneficient. One way to speed up is not to loop over each cell but rather get the data of the surrounding cells, and find the mean:

```
localAverage <- function(im){
    dm <- dim(im)
    size <- prod(dm)
    x <- seq_len(size)
    m <- dm[1]
    
    xm <- x %% m 
    left <- (x - m) * NA^(x <= m) # left index
    up <- (x - 1) * NA^(xm == 1) # up index
    down <- (x + 1) * NA^(!xm) 
    right <- (x + m) * NA^(x > size - m)
    b <- matrix(im[c(left,up,x, down, right)], 5, byrow = TRUE)
    array(colMeans(b, na.rm =  TRUE), dim = dm)
}

set.seed(0)
pic <- matrix(runif(30), 5)
localAverage(pic)

         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.4546293 0.5146388 0.3098210 0.5266930 0.6873031 0.4769267
[2,] 0.6081799 0.5032460 0.3680813 0.6251678 0.5616213 0.4003576
[3,] 0.5387903 0.6105087 0.5463696 0.5191846 0.5059061 0.2485087
[4,] 0.6284957 0.6988927 0.5800774 0.6856513 0.4727331 0.4792857
[5,] 0.7033917 0.6455558 0.5200689 0.4704000 0.5067387 0.4592113
```

---

We could compare this to the above code for an image of 28*28 and 256 * 256 pixels:

```
thomas <- function(pic){
    idx <- row(pic) + 1i * col(pic)
    
    # average by neighboring pixels
    `dim<-`(sapply(c(idx), \(p) {
        u <- idx[abs(p - idx) <= 1] # neighbors + itself
        mean(diag(pic[Re(u), Im(u)]))
    }), dim(pic))
 }

pic28 <- matrix(runif(28^2), 28)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(localAverage(pic28),thomas(pic28), check = 'equal')
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
 localAverage(pic28)    59.6    69.95    94.492    92.95   112.20   181.7   100
       thomas(pic28) 12389.4 12750.10 15582.934 13153.90 20927.75 30250.8   100
 
 pic256 <- matrix(runif(256^2), 256)
bench::mark(localAverage(pic256),thomas(pic256))
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression       min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory    
  <bch:expr>    <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>    
1 localAverage… 59.3µs 64.6µs   14596.    181.6KB     36.5  5204    13      357ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem>
2 thomas(pic25… 12.6ms 13.2ms      73.8    19.1MB     25.7    23     8      312ms <dbl[…]> <Rprofmem>
# ℹ 2 more variables: time <list>, gc <list>
```

Take note of the memory usage also

Comment: nice answer, +1, and your approach inspired me

Answer (score 1):

A follow-up appending to the answer by [@ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77883507/12158757): We can use `for` loops to iterate through each pixels and find out their corresponding neighbors.

This base R implementation with `for` loops is slow, but can significantly save the memory utilization. The performance can be boosted dramatically if you rewrite the `for` loops in terms of `Rcpp`.

## Code

You can takes this version as sort of coding practice

```
ftic2 <- function(pic) {
  nr <- nrow(pic)
  nc <- ncol(pic)
  out <- matrix(NA, nr, nc)
  for (i in 1:nr) {
    ii <- i + c(-1, 1)
    ii <- ii[ii >= 1 & ii <= nr]
    for (j in 1:nc) {
      jj <- j + c(-1, 1)
      jj <- jj[jj >= 1 & jj <= nc]
      out[i, j] <- mean(c(pic[i, j], pic[ii, j], pic[i, jj]))
    }
  }
  out
}
```

## Benchmarking

```
set.seed(0)
pic <- matrix(runif(512^2), 512)
bm <- bench::mark(
  fonyambu = localAverage(pic),
  ftic1 = ftic1(pic),
  ftic2 = ftic2(pic),
  iterations = 100L,
  check = TRUE
)
```

shows (particularly, see the `mem_alloc` column to check the memory status)

```
> bm
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 fonyambu   25.41ms 36.25ms    23.5     59.13MB    27.5    100   117      4.26s
2 ftic1      15.17ms 22.33ms    42.9     38.02MB    27.0    100    63      2.33s
3 ftic2        1.42s   1.51s     0.614    3.09MB     6.23   100  1015      2.72m
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force vectorization with base R:

```
fblur <- function(x) {
  y <- x
  n <- nrow(x)
  m <- ncol(x)
  i <- c(1, n)
  j <- c(1, m)
  y[-1,] <- y[-1,] + x[-n,]
  y[-n,] <- y[-n,] + x[-1,]
  y[,-1] <- y[,-1] + x[,-m]
  y[,-m] <- y[,-m] + x[,-1]
  y[i, j] <- y[i, j]/3
  y[i, -j] <- y[i, -j]/4
  y[-i, j] <- y[-i, j]/4
  y[-i, -j] <- y[-i, -j]/5
  y
}
```

### Benchmarking

Functions:

```
localAverage <- function(im){
  dm <- dim(im)
  size <- prod(dm)
  x <- seq_len(size)
  m <- dm[1]
  
  xm <- x %% m 
  left <- (x - m) * NA^(x <= m) # left index
  up <- (x - 1) * NA^(xm == 1) # up index
  down <- (x + 1) * NA^(!xm) 
  right <- (x + m) * NA^(x > size - m)
  b <- matrix(im[c(left,up,x, down, right)], 5, byrow = TRUE)
  array(colMeans(b, na.rm =  TRUE), dim = dm)
}

ftic1 <- function(pic) {
  p <- list(
    orig = pic,
    up = rbind(NA, pic[-nrow(pic),]),
    down = rbind(pic[-1,], NA),
    left = cbind(NA, pic[, -ncol(pic)]),
    right = cbind(pic[, -1], NA)
  )
  rowMeans(array(do.call(cbind, p), c(dim(pic), 5)), TRUE, 2)
}
```

Data:

```
m <- matrix(runif(512^2), 512)
```

Timings:

```
bench::mark(
  localAverage = localAverage(m),
  ftic1 = ftic1(m),
  fblur = fblur(m)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 localAverage   47.7ms     55ms      13.3    59.2MB     28.4
#> 2 ftic1          31.4ms     35ms      24.5      38MB     33.3
#> 3 fblur          10.2ms   17.4ms      59.1    20.3MB     25.6
```

`fblur` is the fastest and most memory efficient.